CryptoPals spoiler: Stuck on Set 1, Challenge 4 (in Rust)
I'm completely stuck on the named problem. (I am totally fresh to crypto code and not particularly familiar with particularly numerical code in general).
My code looks like this:
fn score(plaintext: &[u8]) -> f64 {
    let mut frequencies: HashMap<_, i32> = HashMap::new();

    for c in plaintext
        .iter()
        .filter(|_c| _c.is_ascii_alphabetic())
        .map(|_c| _c.to_ascii_lowercase())
    {
        frequencies
            .entry(c)
            .and_modify(|ent| *ent += 1)
            .or_insert(1);
    }

    let mut found_distributions: HashMap<_, f64> = HashMap::new();

    for c in (b'a'..b'z').chain(b'A'..b'Z') {
        let freq = frequencies.get(&c).unwrap_or(&0);

        let distribution = *freq as f64 / plaintext.len() as f64;

        found_distributions.insert(c, distribution);
    }

    found_distributions
        .iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| {
            let ground_truth = match k {
                b'e' | b'E' => 0.111607,
                b'a' | b'A' => 0.084966,
                b'r' | b'R' => 0.075809,
                b'i' | b'I' => 0.075448,
                b'o' | b'O' => 0.071635,
                b't' | b'T' => 0.069509,
                b'n' | b'N' => 0.066544,
                b's' | b'S' => 0.057351,
                b'l' | b'L' => 0.054893,
                b'c' | b'C' => 0.045388,
                b'u' | b'U' => 0.036308,
                b'd' | b'D' => 0.033844,
                b'p' | b'P' => 0.031671,
                b'm' | b'M' => 0.030129,
                b'h' | b'H' => 0.030034,
                b'g' | b'G' => 0.024705,
                b'b' | b'B' => 0.020720,
                b'f' | b'F' => 0.018121,
                b'y' | b'Y' => 0.017779,
                b'w' | b'W' => 0.012899,
                b'k' | b'K' => 0.011016,
                b'v' | b'V' => 0.010074,
                b'x' | b'X' => 0.002902,
                b'z' | b'Z' => 0.002722,
                b'j' | b'J' => 0.001965,
                b'q' | b'Q' => 0.001962,
                _ => unreachable!(),
            };

            (ground_truth - v).abs()
        })
        .sum::<f64>()
}

pub fn decrypt(ciphertext: &[u8], key: u8) -> Vec<u8> {
    ciphertext
        .iter()
        .map(|c| c ^ key)
        .collect()
}

pub fn find_min_score_key(ciphertext: &[u8]) -> (u8, f64) {
    let mut best_score = f64::MAX;
    let mut best_key = 0;

    for key in (b'a'..b'z').chain(b'A'..b'Z') {
        let plaintext = decrypt(&ciphertext, key);

        let score = score(&plaintext);

        if score < best_score {
            best_score = score;

            best_key = key;
        }
    }

    (best_key, best_score)
}

pub fn find_single_byte_xor() -> anyhow::Result<(Vec<u8>, f64)> {
    let file = File::open("../4.txt")?;

    let reader = BufReader::new(file);

    let mut min_score = f64::MAX;

    let mut min_line = Vec::new();

    for line in reader.lines() {
        let line = line?;
        let line = line.as_bytes();

        let (key, score) = set_1_challenge_3::find_min_score_key(line);

        let line = decrypt(line, key);
        println!("Line: {}", String::from_utf8(line.clone()).unwrap());

        if score <= min_score {
            min_score = score;

            min_line = line.to_vec();
        }
    }

    anyhow::Ok((min_line, min_score))
}

Some things I've noted are:

The result of find_min_score_key is non-deterministic, it seems, as it unpredictably gives either a normal answer to Question 4, or one with letter cases flipped.
None of the lines evaluated by find_single_byte_xor as being the most likely decoding are logical english sentences, so there is likely some error in find_min_score.

